# Is there a way to force the use of certain sets and let other sets be randomly decided in Matlab neural network?

Tags: matlab, neural-network

My question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22505961/matlab-neural-network-how-to-force-the-use-of-certain-sets). In my classification task I want to test the network with only 11 indices, but I would like to make many classifications and i need Matlab to randomly decide which vectors to use for training and validation, just like in the GUI launched from NNSTART. 
Is that possible?

How do I need to change the following code?

```
net.divideFcn = 'divideind';
net.divideParam.trainInd=1:102;  % The first 127 vectors are for training.
net.dividnet.divideParam.valInd=103:127;    % The next 25 vectors are for validation.
net.divideParam.testInd=128:138; % The last 11 vectors are for testing the network.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could assign those numbers in a random way I guess.

something like:

```
indx=103:138;
rand_indx=indx(randperm(length(indx))); % reorder them randomly

net.dividnet.divideParam.valInd=rand_indx(1:25);    % The next 25 vectors are for validation.
net.divideParam.testInd=rand_indx(26:end); % The last 11 vectors are for testing the network.
```

Comment: @dzsezusz Hard-coding random indexes? Why didn't you use this approach?

Comment: I divided my training and validation sets manually using a switch-case statement, i then made my classifications. It worked perfectly for my problem.

Comment: @dzsezusz I guess, but it makes more sense to do it programatically, both for further readability and to avoid selecting the right data manually, the human factor. In the end, why would you program in you are going to do it by hand!?