# Matlab - neural networks - How to use different datasets for training, validation and testing?

Tags: matlab, neural-network

Best

I've a question about Neural networks in Matlab.

First of all, I've a small NN, 2 inputs, 1 hidden layer with 10 neurons and one output. And this works fine. But the question which I've is. Can I determine my training date, validation data and test data?

I know, if I use e.g. *net = feedforwardnet(10);* that I can divide my *overall dataset* into e.g.70/100 15/100 and 15/100. But I don't want to do this, because in this case I want to train my NN with a 1000 data-points, validate them with another data-points and use another independent data-set of 1000 data-points to test them. With other words, I want to control these 3 interdependent data-sets.

Thus, can someone help me?

Kind regards

Edit, I don't want to use a data-set with 3000 data-points and set the devideParams on 1/3 1/3 & 1/3.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Matlab neural network, how to force the use of certain sets for training, validation and testing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22505961/matlab-neural-network-how-to-force-the-use-of-certain-sets-for-training-valida)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best myself

When you use a `feedforwardnet` then you can define your divide parameters

```
net.divideParam.trainRatio = 1/3;
net.divideParam.valRatio = 1/3;
net.divideParam.testRatio = 1/3;
```

You know that your data will be divided into 3 pieces.
But you (I) didn't know which data.

But when you and thus I, train my network via the following command line:

```
[net,tr]=train(net,x,t);
```

then, `tr` will contain all the necessary info, like for example :

```
tr.trainInd 1x1000 double, 
tr.valInd  1x1000 double, 
tr.testInd  1x1000 double,
```

Thus, e.g. tr.trainInd, will contain all the indexes of our set of data which were used for training. Also, in `tr`, we can see that the type of `tr.divideFcn` is set on `dividerand` which means that the indexes are picked at random. Thus it would be logical, that there is a possibility that those indexes aren't picked randomly which means that, if we combine both things. It should be possible to use another test set --> `net.divideParam.testRatio = 0` and to use two different train and validation sets --> `net.divideParam.trainRatio = 1/2` and `net.divideParam.valRatio = 1/2` - If you can set the `tr.divideFcn` on something chronological, sequential. Last but not least, if this is possible then we have nothing more to do, then put the training and validation set into one data set, etc...

Kind regards to myself

Answer (score 0):

By default it will use a random index for train,validation,test. This is manually set with the following, though since it's default usually not needed:

```
net.divideFcn = 'dividerand'
```

and then you use the the commands you noted above:

```
net.divideParam.trainRatio = 1/3;
net.divideParam.valRatio = 1/3;
net.divideParam.testRatio = 1/3;
```

To do what you want and set the index of each you can do the following:

```
net.divideFcn = 'divideind'
net.divideParam.trainInd = [1:1000]
net.divideParam.valInd=[1001:2000]
net.divideParam.testInd=[2001:3000]
```